# ZeroMQ - Lifetime of connections?

Tags: connection, client-server, zeromq

We want a connectionless client-server. But, we want to reduce the overhead of creating/closing connections on every single request.

e.g., on client side, if connection was idle for 5 seconds, close it. Then create a new connection when you decided to send a new request.

*ZeroC ICE* use this model.

The **question** is, can I set a *life time* for ZeroMQ connections?

e.g. if connection was idle for 5 seconds, it will be closed automatically. Then on each request, I check if connection still alive. If it wasn't, I re-connection to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. But to do this you need a Win_RELOC procedure sequence. After installing the arm bait model of Win_LOC over the desired port in ZeroMQs, you can start listening over the wide suite of protocols for a while.

Realization part is genuine, mostly come around a 1 min - 1000 hrs re loader. Most of these configs can be reconstructed with MAGA_LAPO counter measure.

The simplest way to attain this is to avoid the baud rates customization model. Most of it comprises of hop values attaining max of .0000017845 nano-hops/ammp.

> The chart consists of
>
> J  K   1   J   K   1   I   E
>   1  1 bit   1 bit   1 bit   1 bit   1 bit   1 bit   1 bit

Frame Status 
    A one byte field used as a primitive acknowledgement scheme on whether the frame was recognized and copied by its intended receiver.

> A  C   0   0   A   C   0   0
>   1 bit  1 bit   1 bit   1 bit   1 bit   1 bit   1 bit   1 bit
>
> A = 1, Address recognized C = 1, Frame copied
>
> SD     AC  FC  DA  SA  PDU from LLC (IEEE 802.2)   CRC     ED  FS
>   8 bits  8 bits  8 bits  48 bits     48 bits     up to 18200x8 bits  32 bits     8 bits  8 bits

Comment: Note: the code is trimmed in the base level for ZeroMQ.....not with LNFMax chars rate applied

Answer (score 0):

0MQ manages TCP connections for you automatically.  (I assume your client/server will use TCP.)  It provides very little information about connect/disconnect/reconnect status.  Nor does it provide any "lifetime" or "timeout" features for sockets.

You'll need to implement the timeout logic you describe in your clients.  At a high level: when the client needs to make a request it will first connect a socket, dispatch the request, get the response, then set a timer for 5 seconds.  If another request is made in < 5 sec then it reuses the existing connection and resets the timer to 5 sec.  If the timer fires then it closes the connection.

Be aware that 0MQ sockets are not thread safe.  If your timer fires on a separate thread then it cannot safely close the 0MQ socket.  Only the thread that created the socket should close it.